# Appending items after a number of collisions

Tags: python, arrays, list, pygame

How do I re-code this so instead of the block being appended the first time its hit, it's appended/removed after being hit *five times*- whenever I made any small edits to this line of code portions of my game disappear.

I tried to make a variable, "easy_block_hits" and then say, when easy_block_hits == 5, append block from list, but it makes everything disappear..

```
    easy_kept_blocks = []    
    for block in easy_blocks:    
        if block.colliderect(ball):
            speed[1] = -speed[1]
            easy_block_hits += 1

        else:
            easy_kept_blocks.append(block)
    easy_blocks = easy_kept_blocks
```

EXAMPLE OF ME TRYING TO CHANGE IT AND LINES OF BLOCKS DISAPEARING

if I tried rephrasing it to;

```
    easy_kept_blocks = []    
    for block in easy_blocks:    
        if block.colliderect(ball):
            speed[1] = -speed[1]
            easy_block_hits += 1

        elif easy_block_hits == 5:
            easy_kept_blocks.append(block)
    easy_blocks = easy_kept_blocks
```

the blue block line disapears.

here is the full code, I have a feeling if you give me a solution it will not work so maybe it has to do with the rest of my code?

```
#December 16, 2019
#Final Project - Breakout

#IMPORTING LIBRARIES-----
import pygame
import sys
import time

#INITIALIZING SCREEN SIZE-----
pygame.init()
screen_size = (597, 700)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_size),0)
pygame.display.set_caption("BREAKOUT")

#retrieve screen measurements
screen_w = screen.get_width()
screen_h = screen.get_height()

#retrieve position of center of screen
center_x = int(screen_w/2)
center_y = int(screen_h/2)

#COLOURS-----
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
RED = (255,0,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
PURPLE = (154, 136, 180)

#BACKGROUND-----
screen.fill(BLACK)
pygame.display.update()


#PICTURES-----
background_image = pygame.image.load("space_background.png")
easy_block_image = pygame.image.load("easy_block.png")
medium_block_image = pygame.image.load("medium_block.png")
hard_block_image = pygame.image.load("hard_block.png")
metal_block_image = pygame.image.load("metal_block.png")
paddle_image = pygame.image.load("paddle.png")
ball_image = pygame.image.load("ball.png")
#title_image = pygame.image.load("S4.png")
#block/paddle/ball pictures were created on pixilart.com by myself
#background - https://www.wallpaperflare.com/dragon-flying-above-sky-artwork-wallpaper-181535
#title made from fontmeme.com

#SPEED-----
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60 #set frames per second
speed = [4,4]
paddle_speed = 6

#VARIABLES-----

#paddle
paddle_x = center_x
paddle_y = 600
paddle_w = 78
paddle_h = 10

paddle_dx = 0
paddle_dy = 0

#ball
ball_x = center_x
ball_y = center_y
ball_w = 12
ball_h = 12

#blocks
block_x = 5
block_w = 40
block_h = 10

#severity block positions
easy_block_y = 172
medium_block_y = 148
hard_block_y = 124
metal_block_y = 100

#severity block hits
easy_block_hits = 0

#lives displayed
lives_displayed_h = 10
lives_displayed_x = 4
lives_displayed_y = screen_h - (lives_displayed_h + 5)
lives_displayed_w = 79

#title
title_x = 5
title_y = 5
title_w = 240
title_h = 50

#test rect
rx = 0
ry = 700
rw = 700
rh = 1

#RECTS-----
paddle = pygame.Rect(paddle_x, paddle_y, paddle_w, paddle_h)
ball = pygame.Rect(ball_x, ball_y, ball_w, ball_h)
title = pygame.Rect(title_x, title_y, title_w, title_h)
lives_displayed_rect = pygame.Rect(lives_displayed_x,lives_displayed_y,lives_displayed_w,lives_displayed_h)
testrect = pygame.Rect(rx, ry, rw, rh)


#FUNCTIONS-----

#https://nerdparadise.com/programming/pygameblitopacity
def blit_alpha(target, source, location, opacity):
        x = location[0]
        y = location[1]
        temp = pygame.Surface((source.get_width(), source.get_height())).convert()
        temp.blit(target, (-x, -y))
        temp.blit(source, (0, 0))
        temp.set_alpha(opacity)        
        target.blit(temp, location)

#ARRAYS-----

#empty array to store rects for each block row of level
easy_blocks = []
medium_blocks = []
hard_blocks = []
metal_blocks = []
lives_displayed = []

#layout of blocks for each level
easy_block_array = [
"B B B B B B B B B B B B B B",
"B B B B B B B B B B B B B B",
]

medium_block_array = [
"P P P P P P P P P P P P P P",
"P P P P P P P P P P P P P P",
]

hard_block_array = [
"I I I I I I I I I I I I I I",
"I I I I I I I I I I I I I I",
]

metal_block_array = [
"G G G G G G G G G G G G G G",
"G G G G G G G G G G G G G G",
]

lives_displayed_array = [
"L L L",
]

#read the array and create the appropriate Rects FOR EACH LEVEL, store them in the walls array
for row in easy_block_array: #easy/blue
    for col in row:
        if col == "B":
            easy_block_rect = pygame.Rect(block_x, easy_block_y, block_w, block_h)
            easy_blocks.append(easy_block_rect)
        block_x += 21
    easy_block_y += 12
    block_x = 5

for row in medium_block_array: #medium/purple
    for col in row:
        if col == "P":
            medium_block_rect = pygame.Rect(block_x, medium_block_y, block_w, block_h)
            medium_blocks.append(medium_block_rect)
        block_x += 21
    medium_block_y += 12
    block_x = 5

for row in hard_block_array: #hard/pink
    for col in row:
        if col == "I":
            hard_block_rect = pygame.Rect(block_x, hard_block_y, block_w, block_h)
            hard_blocks.append(hard_block_rect)
        block_x += 21
    hard_block_y += 12
    block_x = 5

for row in metal_block_array: #metal/gray
    for col in row:
        if col == "G":
            metal_block_rect = pygame.Rect(block_x, metal_block_y, block_w, block_h)
            metal_blocks.append(metal_block_rect)
        block_x += 21
    metal_block_y += 12
    block_x = 5

for row in lives_displayed_array: #lives/paddle
    for col in row:
        if col == "L":
            lives_displayed_rect = pygame.Rect(lives_displayed_x, lives_displayed_y, lives_displayed_w, lives_displayed_h)
            lives_displayed.append(lives_displayed_rect)
        lives_displayed_x += 41
    lives_displayed_y += 12
    lives_displayed_x = 5

#LOOPS-----
intro_screen = False
game_screen = False
end_screen = False

#----------INTRO_SCREEN LOOP----------

#----------GAME_SCREEN LOOP----------
game = True
while game:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type ==pygame.QUIT:
            game = False
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        #moving paddle with keys
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                paddle_dx = -paddle_speed
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                paddle_dx = paddle_speed

    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        paddle_dx = 0

    #constrain this loop to the specified FPS
    clock.tick(FPS)

    #PADDLE EVENTS-----

    #store old paddle positions
    old_paddle_x = paddle.x
    old_paddle_y = paddle.y

    #moving the paddle rect
    paddle.move_ip(paddle_dx, paddle_dy)

    #check to see if rect has left screen
    if paddle.left < 0 or paddle.right > screen_w:
        paddle.x = old_paddle_x

    #BALL EVENTS-----

    #moving ball
    ball = ball.move(speed)

    #collision bounce left & right
    if ball.left < 0 or ball.right > screen_w:
        speed[0] = -speed[0]

    #collision bounce top & bottom
    if ball.top < 0:
        speed[1] = -speed[1]

    #collision with bottom - life removed
    lives_displayed_kept = []
    for life in lives_displayed:
        if ball.bottom > screen_h:
            speed[1] = -speed[1]
        else:
            lives_displayed_kept.append(life)
    lives_displayed = lives_displayed_kept

    #collision of ball with paddle
    if paddle.colliderect(ball):
        speed[1] = -speed[1]

    #BLOCKS EVENTS-----

    #for blue (easy) blocks
    easy_kept_blocks = []    
    for block in easy_blocks:    
        if block.colliderect(ball):
            speed[1] = -speed[1]
            easy_block_hits += 1

        else:
            easy_kept_blocks.append(block)
    easy_blocks = easy_kept_blocks

    #for purple (medium) blocks
    medium_kept_blocks = []    
    for block in medium_blocks:    
        if block.colliderect(ball):
            speed[1] = -speed[1]
            easy_block_hits += 1
        else:
            medium_kept_blocks.append(block)
    medium_blocks = medium_kept_blocks

    #for pink (hard) blocks
    hard_kept_blocks = []    
    for block in hard_blocks:    
        if block.colliderect(ball):
            speed[1] = -speed[1]
        else:
            hard_kept_blocks.append(block)
    hard_blocks = hard_kept_blocks

    #for gray (metal) blocks
    metal_kept_blocks = []    
    for block in metal_blocks:    
        if block.colliderect(ball):
            speed[1] = -speed[1]
        else:
            metal_kept_blocks.append(block)
    metal_blocks = metal_kept_blocks

    #DRAWING/CREATING OBJECTS-----

    #removes screen trail
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    screen.blit(background_image, [0, 0])

    #drawing paddle/ball inside rect
    screen.blit(paddle_image, paddle)
    screen.blit(ball_image, ball)
    #screen.blit(title_image, title)

    #draws a block for each "B"
    for block in easy_blocks:
        screen.blit(easy_block_image, block)

    #draws a block for each "P"
    for block in medium_blocks:
        screen.blit(medium_block_image, block)

    #draws a block for each "I"
    for block in hard_blocks:
        screen.blit(hard_block_image, block)

    #draws a block for each "G"
    for block in metal_blocks:
        screen.blit(metal_block_image, block)

    #draws a paddle life for each "L"
    for life in lives_displayed:
        screen.blit(paddle_image, life)

    #----------END_SCREEN LOOP----------

    #updating the screen
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: "whenever I made any small edits to this line of code portions of my game disappear" can you give an example

Comment: Ok, in #for blue (easy) blocks, take the line of coding, "easy_kept_blocks.append(block)", and the entire line blue blocks disappear when you run it.

Comment: Please include this information in the original question

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your game’s logic is the following:

1. Create an empty list
2. If block is hit, increase the counter
3. Else, blocks that’s not hit will be kept by appending each to the list `easy_kept_blocks`

Now if you change the code in the way described, the level will be empty until 5 blocks are hit, but that can’t happen because there are no blocks to hit.

One way to do what you described would be creating another list with counters for each block. And if any block counter reaches 5, exclude the block from being appended.

An example would be:

```
easy_block_counter = [0] * len(easy_blocks) # under ARRAYS

...
new_easy_block_counter = []
easy_kept_blocks = []    
for count, block in zip(easy_block_counter, easy_blocks):    
    if block.colliderect(ball):
        speed[1] = -speed[1]
        count += 1
    if count < 5:
        new_easy_block_counter.append(count)
        easy_kept_blocks.append(block)
easy_blocks = easy_kept_blocks
easy_block_counter = new_easy_block_counter
```

It may be nicer to have different block classes with the count as one attribute. This way you can add other attributes (e.g. power ups!!) as well. :)

Comment: I tried the code and even something inspired by it and it didn't work :(. (Also I'd love to add classes if I knew how)

Comment: @IJH I’ve fixed the code above. See if it works now.